# WildFly 11 ActiveMQ Web Console

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I am quite new to JMS. I know that WildFly 11 has a activeMQ JMS built inside it and we can certainly add a new ActiveMQ to it. But is there a way to get a web console for the inbuilt ActiveMQ, or is there a way inwhich we can monitor the JMS Queues and Topics like in a standalone ActiveMQ instance.

Thanks in advance.

PS:
Long story short, need to get a GUI interface that can intercept and show JMS messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildfly has a web console of its own which may suit your needs. It shows basic queue metrics like consumer count, message count, messages added, and scheduled count.

If you want a console that goes beyond that you *might* be able to deploy the console shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis to Wildfly (e.g. by copying the war files).  However, I've not done this before so I don't know how well it would work.

Another option would be to deploy ActiveMQ Artemis standalone and use that instead of the instance of ActiveMQ Artemis embedded into Wildfly. This would give you easy, simple access to the web console shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis.